# Jquery slideUp problem

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with accordion menu.

I have something like this.

```
<ul>
 <li>Option 1</li>
  <ul>
   <li>Sub opt 1</li>
   <li>Sub opt 2</li>
  </ul>
 <li>Option 2</li>
  <ul>
   <li>aaa</li>
...
```

I have set them slide up, so they are closed.
When i click on Sub opt 1, i get redirected, and my list is slide up again.
Is there any way, that the parent of the `<li>` i clicked, would be set to slide down.
So that you know on which "category" you are on.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to know what menu you clicked on after redirect. You can add a "active" class for the clicked menu you return html page. Ex:

```
<ul>
 <li>Option 1</li>
  <ul>
   <li>Sub opt 1</li>
   <li>Sub opt 2</li>
  </ul>
 <li class="active">Option 2</li>
  <ul>
   <li>aaa</li>
...
```

Based on the active class you can call slidedown function for that <li>.

Comment: But how to know, on which one I / you clicked

Comment: I think your menus are related to specific pages. So, you will know which menu you should set "active".

Answer (score 1):

You could set an anchor tag in your URL (e.g page.html#tag)

Then, in JavaScript, you can use this plugin [jQuery-URL-Parser](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser) to get the jQuery.url.attr('anchor') :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand things correctly, you want your multi-level menu to expand automatically when a new page is loaded by clicking a submenu item.

If you want to do this solely on the client side, you've got two options:

1. Determine the active menu item by comparing the current URL with the list items
2. Set a cookie when clicking a menu item

I'd prefer option 2, so here's a small example in pseudo-jQuery: <sub>(which means this won't work out of the box :))</sub>

```
$('.menu-item').click(function() {
    // set cookie 'currentMenuItem' to $(this).href()
    // redirect page to $(this).href()
});

// your DOM load call, which is called after the page loads
$(function() {
    var cookie = getCurrentMenuItemCookie();
    if (cookie) {
        var parent = determineMenuParent();
        if (parent) {
            expandAccordion(parent);
        }
    }

});
```